# Burning a data disc from files in folder

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know how I can make my Mac application (in Objective-C) burn a disc with any burner.  I need to get the app to prompt the user to insert a blank disc, and once the user has inserted one, the program will start burning all the files in a specific folder to the disc, using the DiscRecording and DiscRecordingUI frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be an old demo for doing this with the 10.5 developer examples. I found a link to some sample on the apple reference library [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=DiscRecording) that has a sample application for dvd burning. Hope that can help! I really wish apple still included the many examples that used to come with the developer package.